# How to upload the project on goviralhost.com

Tags: python, flask, deployment, z-index

My project is hosted on GitHub, and I've successfully linked it to goviralhost using Git version control.
Initial Errors:

Initially, I encountered some errors during the deployment process on goviralhost. I was able to identify and rectify these issues, ensuring that the project structure and configurations align with the requirements.

The Flask app works perfectly on my local server. I have confirmed that the application runs as expected in the development environment.

However, when I try to access my deployed website on goviralhost, the webpage only displays "It works! Python v3.7.16." instead of my actual Flask application.

I have added a requirements.txt file listing the dependencies.
I synced my project files to goviralhost file manager through GitHub version control.
I created a Python app on goviralhost.com.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.